# InnoSetup setting up desktop shortcut for node-webkit apps

Tags: node.js, webkit, inno-setup

I am setting up an installer for [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) desktop app. I have successfully created an app shortcut but I can't create a desktop shortcut because it requires an exe file. I am passing working directory reference to nw.exe in shortcut it works fine but there seems no option for creating a custom desktop icon. Here is my inno setup config file:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}/node-webkit/nw.exe" ; Parameters: "."; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcon}"
```

Following code creates a desktop shortcut. Is there any way I can pass above icon reference to desktop icon?

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";
```

Comment: You cannot *pass an icon reference to the desktop icon* anyhow. That makes no sense. If you mean how to conditionally create that icon if the task is checked, then use the [`Tasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) parameter in your `[Icons]` entry like `...; Tasks: desktopicon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer if anyone is looking for a solution. Thanks TLama.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "your.exe" ; Parameters: "."; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcon}";  Tasks: desktopicon

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";
```